# Prevent TinyMCE from changing spaces into [nbsp]

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE v4, and often spaces are encoded as [nbsp]. I know that this is supposed to happen when you have multiple spaces, but it often also happens when making a small edit to the text, e.g. the adjoining spaces covert too even though they are single.

The best would be if I could simply switch off encoding for spaces. Is this possible, and if so how? I could not find anything when searching online. There is a configuration file I'm using (tinyMCE.php), and that includes **tinymce.init({**. Maybe something could be done here?

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

Change the entity encoding to raw.

```
entity_encoding: raw,
```